# Mongoose MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an application with separate folders for backend and frontend. This is how the file structure looks like:

```
/root
  backend.js
    /models
      Store.js
  /frontend
    frontend.js
```

When I use the Store model in backend.js everything works fine. If I'd like to use the Store model in frontend.js I get the Schema hasn't been registered for model "Store"... error.
In **backend.js** I simply require the model after connected to the database:

```
require('./models/Store');
```

And later in the code, I can use it like

```
const Store = mongoose.model('Store');
```

In **frontend.js** the require looks like this:

```
require('../models/Store');
```

But when I try to use the model `const Store = mongoose.model('Store');` I get an error.

I already tried requiring it like this:

```
const path = require('path');
require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../models/Store'));
```

and like this:

```
require('../models/Store')(mongoose);
```

But none of those seems to solve the problem.

The strange thing is that if I do something like this:

```
const myStoreModel = require('../models/Store');
console.log(myStoreModel);
```

The result of the log is `Model { Store }`. So it looks like the path is fine, and the Model is also there, still, when I try to use it, I get the same MissingSchemaError.

What am I missing?

Comment: I presume "frontend" and "backend" means that different applications are actually using the same codebase. In which case you actually do need to `require()` in **both**. If they are separate applications, then just because you have `require()` in the "backend" does not make that visible to the "frontend". The reason `mongoose.model("Store")` works ( **after** a `requrre()` ) is because that statment loaded the code into memory **for that application**. This does not apply to *separate* applications. i.e "frontend" and "backend".

Comment: @NeilLunn frontend and backend are just sharing the models, everything else is different. I use require() in both backend and frontend. 
Backend.js require looks like this: `require('./models/Store')` and frontend.js require is `require('../models/Store')`.
Basically, I'm doing the same thing in backend.js and frontend.js, the only difference is the path.

Comment: To be clear, the specific error is caused by **NOT** actually doing the require and simply including a statement with `mongoose.model("Store")` with **no prior** invocation of `mongoose.model("Store", storeSchema)`. Basically it's mongoose complaining that you have not registered the schema yet since you did not `require` the file in which that schema registration was actually made. You might want to check your execution order of those `require` statements in comparison to the later statement.

Comment: @NeilLunnt I've checked the execution order and it's the same for frontend and backend: connect to the db, require the model, use the model. Works fine in backend, doesn't work in frontend. I've made a copy of the `models` folder into the `frontend` folder, changed the require in frontend.js to `require('./models/Store')` and this way, it works fine. That's why I'm assuming that something is wrong with the `require` part. Thank you for trying to help!